# drawing a line moves like a clock pointer in pygame

Tags: pygame

I am trying to draw a line moving in the same way as a clock pointer , but when i run the program the line move like 20 degrees then the program got frozen , and i can read that :"ValueError: math domain error"
here is the code i have written :

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 600), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("circle_line")

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (250, 250, 250)


R = 50
CIRCLE_LINE_START_X = 150
CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y = 300
CIRCLE_LINE_END_X = CIRCLE_LINE_START_X
CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y - R


MOVE_SPEED = 3




while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()



    if CIRCLE_LINE_END_X <= CIRCLE_LINE_START_X and CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y <= CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y :
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X -= MOVE_SPEED
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)) + CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y

    if CIRCLE_LINE_END_X <= CIRCLE_LINE_START_X and CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y >= CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y :
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X += MOVE_SPEED
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)) + CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y

    if CIRCLE_LINE_END_X >= CIRCLE_LINE_START_X and CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y >= CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y :
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X += MOVE_SPEED
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)) + CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y

    if CIRCLE_LINE_END_X >= CIRCLE_LINE_START_X and CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y <= CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y :
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X -= MOVE_SPEED
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)) + CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y




    windowSurface.fill(WHITE) 
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLACK, (CIRCLE_LINE_START_X, CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y), (CIRCLE_LINE_END_X, CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y), 3)

    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

any help to find out my mistake will be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Can you post the entire contents of the error?  It should include line numbers where the error is occurring, which will help us find the bug.

Comment: here is the error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Desktop/circle_line.py", line 47, in <module>
    CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)) + CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y
ValueError: math domain error

Answer (score 3):

This error is because you are trying to calculate the square root of a negative number, concretely the result of `R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)`.

However, if you want to draw something based on a circular movement, I suggest you to use a variable called `DEGREES` and increment it in each iteration. Then you can use `math.sin` and `math.cos` to calculate the distance based on the angle.

Comment: thank you A Rodas , you are right the number under sqrt was negative when it is arriving to the edges of the diameter .

Answer (score 0):

i made some modulations in the algorithm i had used , and this code is giving acceptable result comparing with the code above , here is the code for who is interesting:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 600), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("circle_line")

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (250, 250, 250)


R = 50
CIRCLE_LINE_START_X = 150
CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y = 300
MIN_X = CIRCLE_LINE_START_X - R
MAX_X = CIRCLE_LINE_START_X + R
CIRCLE_LINE_END_X = MIN_X 
CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)) + CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y




MOVE_SPEED = 5 # has to be a number where as ( R % MOVE_SPEED = 0 )
DIRECTION = "right"



while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()


    if CIRCLE_LINE_END_X >= MAX_X   :
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X = MAX_X
        DIRECTION = "left"


    if CIRCLE_LINE_END_X <= MIN_X  :
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X = MIN_X
        DIRECTION = "right"

    if DIRECTION == "right":
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X += MOVE_SPEED 
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2)) + CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y

    if DIRECTION == "left":
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_X -= MOVE_SPEED
        CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y = CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y - math.sqrt(R**2 - ((CIRCLE_LINE_END_X - CIRCLE_LINE_START_X)**2))  



    windowSurface.fill(WHITE) 
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, BLACK, (CIRCLE_LINE_START_X, CIRCLE_LINE_START_Y), (CIRCLE_LINE_END_X, CIRCLE_LINE_END_Y), 3)

    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```